# Deserialization of a JSON using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

I am receiving a JSON from a server that resembles the following syntax and I require some  assistance deserializing & parsing it. I have done a lot of reading on this and have found that using GSON is really useful! ( I Will post any updates to my code here)

(Corrected JSON):

```
    [{
    "name" : "Zone1",
    "types" : [{"datatype":"string","brand":"string","index":0},
            {"datatype":"string","value":"int32,"index":1},
            {"datatype":"string","url":"string,"index":2}]
    "data" : [["gucci",2,"www.whoami12345.com"]]
   },
   {
   "name" : "Zone2",
   "types" : [{"datatype":"string","brand":"string","index":0},
            {"datatype":"string","value":"int32,"index":1},
            {"datatype":"string","url":"string,"index":2}]
   "data" : [["nike", 23,"www.nike.com"]]
  }]
```

I found this site [Link](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/) pretty neat because it explains how to use gson and explains deserialisation well. My understanding of the JSON that I have is that it is an array and the data field is an array of Arrays.

My question is how do I go about parsing this? I have a function that will take a string searching for a specific zone name. After the deserialisation takes place and an entry matches the correct zone, the datatype and url are supposed to be returned. From that article, my understanding is that I should be using a JSONArray. Any feedback would be appreciated. Below is some code of what I have started

```
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

String name;    

public class data{
    String brand;
    int num;
    int url;
 }

public class types{
    String datatype;
    int value;
    String url;
}


public types Deserialiser(String json, String zone){ // this is the json string that will be passed into the function


JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray();
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.size();i++){
   String temp = jsonArray.get(i).get("name");
   if (temp.equals(zone){
      index =i;
      break;
   }

}

....

types jsonTypes = new types();
// set everything else
return jsonTypes;
}
```

Comment: Right.  That's not (valid) JSON.  If you print out your `json` String, you will find that it does not match the syntax you find at json.org.

Comment: Still not valid JSON.

Comment: Hint:  There are bugs in lines 1, 2, 5, and 7.

Comment: 1 sec let me correct this

Comment: As to how you parse it, you have a List of Maps.  Two of the three Map keys correspond to Lists, and one of those Lists contains another List.  (If you go to json.org and study the syntax this will make more sense.)

Comment: @HotLicks sorry mate my internet fried out last night

Comment: Json has been corrected, is there a way to deserialize this or do I have to build my own deserializer? All I want to do is map this to some class variables

Answer (score 1):

Valid JSON (I think):

```
[{"name"  : "Zone1",
   "types" : ["datatype":"string","value":"int","url":"string"],
   "data"  : [["gucci",2,"www.whoami12345.com"]]},
  {"name"  : "Zone2",
   "types" : ["datatype":"string","value":"int","url":"string"],
   "data"  : [["nike", 23,"www.nike.com"]]}
]
```

Nope -- wrong missing "object" brackets

Try again:

```
[{"name"  : "Zone1",
   "types" : [{"datatype":"string","value":"int","url":"string"}],
   "data"  : [["gucci",2,"www.whoami12345.com"]]},
  {"name"  : "Zone2",
   "types" : [{"datatype":"string","value":"int","url":"string"}],
   "data"  : [["nike", 23,"www.nike.com"]]}
]
```

Ah!! Much better!

Comment: Yeah I have corrected my JSON , I was doing it off the top of my head before my internet failed. Please advise

Comment: @Masterminder - The very first and last quotes don't belong there.  (Paste into a [JSON online parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/) to check your syntax.)

Comment: @Masterminder - And you're missing a quote after "string" here `"string,"index"`.

Comment: how would I go about extracting the "data" field and recurse through that array of arrays? Can you show me some code? I am assuming you have to use a JsonArray

Comment: or simply extract that first element(which is an array) from that array and then recurse through that array

Comment: First get a pointer to the outermost object containing the data (a JSONArray/List in this case).  Access that object (write a loop to index through the array) and operate on each object contained therein (a JSONObject/Map in this case).  Access *that* object to obtain whatever your next goal is.  Etc.  Peel it like an onion, a layer at a time.  You may end up with several nested loops, of course, but that's what the data asks for.

Comment: so after doing this: JsonArray jsonDataArray = jsonObject.get("data").getAsJsonArray(); do I have to map this to another JsonArray? So like: JsonArray jsonDataEntry = jsonDataArray.get(0) ?

Comment: I'm not real big on GSON, but I think it should start with `JsonArray jsonArray = json.getAsJsonArray();`.  Then iterate on the array and get each element as JsonObject.

Comment: okay but do you know if the "[[{...}]]" symbolizes a JsonArray of JsonArrays?

Comment: Read the documentation at json.org.